# $ time equivalent in Windows Cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

What is the equivalent of `$ time reallylongtask --foo` in Windows Command Prompt? Or maybe is there another way to see the time of execution of a command in Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: just in case, there is a similar topic on StackOverflow: [How do I measure execution time of a command on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: Check if the following link is helpful with you: https://ilostmynotes.blogspot.com/2015/05/measure-windows-cmdexe-command.html